# How to show only the contents of a folder in AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: typescript, list, concatenation

I am trying to get the content of folders when clicked. Now I am getting the folder name then the content.

MyDocument/test.txt
MyDocument/test2.txt
....

I need to show only the contents:
test.txt
test2.txt

here is what I have:

```
getFolderContent(): Observable<any> {
return new Observable((observer) => {
  this.loader.next(false);
  bucket.listObjectsV2({ Bucket: this.bucketName, Prefix: this.currentFolder, Delimiter: '/' }, (err: AWS.AWSError, data: S3.ListObjectsV2Output) => {
    this.loader.next(false);
    console.log(data)
    if (err) {
      observer.error(err);
    }
    else {
      let list: any[] = [];
      list = list.concat(data.CommonPrefixes?.map(m => { return { name: m.Prefix, contentType: 'folder' } }));
      list = list.concat(data.Contents?.filter(m => m.Key != this.currentFolder).map(m => { return { name: m.Key, contentType: 'file', modifiedTime: m.LastModified?.toDateString() } }));
      observer.next(list);
    }

  });
})}
```

I think it has to do with the list but not sure how to do that?